# Items of feature_columns must be a _FeatureColumn. Given (type <class 'str'>): sepal length (cm)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I am training a NN model on iris dataset

```py
*from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()

X = iris['data']

y = iris['target']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3)

import tensorflow.contrib.learn as learn

classifier.fit(X_train,y_train,steps=200,batch_size=32)*
```

**On the above step while executing it , it's showing this error

Its showing this error:

```
**Items of feature_columns must be a _FeatureColumn. Given (type <class 'str'>): sepal length (cm).**
```

Also I am using Google Colaboratory and I am a rookie in NN and Tensor Flow.
Can someone answer about this doubt?**

Also i am searching on google but got noting much that can help me.

Comment: What is your `classifier`?

Comment: classifier = learn.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10,20,10],n_classes=3) .  Actually when i run this it says  __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'feature_columns'               Don't know how to solve this. @aminrd .                                                                                  After that  on line                            classifier.fit(X_train,y_train,steps=200,batch_size=32)

Comment: It shows                                                                                                                          Items of feature_columns must be a _FeatureColumn. Given (type <class 'str'>): sepal length (cm).            But i am new to this so unable to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parameters like:

```py
input_train = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
                  x = {'x': X_train},
                  y = y_train,
                  num_epochs = 200,
                  shuffle = True)

feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key='x', shape=(X_train.shape[1],))]

classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
                       hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                       n_classes=3,
                       optimizer='Adagrad'
                       feature_columns=feature_columns)

# Instead of fit, you should use .train() and pass intput_train
classifier.train(input_train)
```